# Is a passport required for travelling to Nepal from India by air?

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, indian-citizens, nepal

I'm an Indian citizen and I want to travel to Nepal by air. Is a passport required?

Comment: Is a passport required to cross the land border? Does the Nepalese embassy in India have a web site? How about the Nepalese immigration service?

Comment: -1 because we are not a Google service.

Comment: Indians do not require visa travelling to Nepal but only have today posses passport or driving license or election commission card.It is also advisable today have 2 - 3 Passport size photos in hand.

Comment: +1 as this is the top post that comes up when I search "do Indians need a passport to visit Nepal" on Google.

Answer (score 9):

It seems it is not required; as stated at the [airport's website](http://www.tiairport.com.np/):

> Visas are required for all foreigners wishing to enter into Nepal
>   **except for Indian nationalities, who need to fish out their identity
>   at the counter to identify themselves.**

Further from the Nepal Tourism Board's [welcomenepal.com website](http://www.welcomenepal.com/travel-essentials/visa-information/):

> Indian nationals do not require visa to enter Nepal. As per the
>   Nepalese Immigration, Indian Nationals Traveling to Nepal must posses
>   any One of the following documents:
>
> 1. Passport
> 2. Driving License with photo
> 3. Photo Identity card issued by a Government Agency
> 4. Ration Card with Photo
> 5. Election Commission Card with Photo
> 6. Identity Card issued by Embassy of India in Kathmandu
> 7. Identity Card with Photo issued by Sub- Divisional Magistrate or any other officials above his rank
>
> Also, please check with your nearest travel agents for documents
>   required by the Indian Immigration for Indians traveling to Nepal.